# How to output "something" in SQLite3 python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

i use this but i recive:<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000253A4735960>*
pls help with output

````
with sq.connect("WordBase.db") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()

print(cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM word WHERE ROWID=1
'''))```
````

Answer (score 2):

Execute is just an instruction to [execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) a SQL Statement

> To retrieve data after executing a SELECT statement, either treat the cursor as an iterator, call the cursor’s fetchone() method to retrieve a single matching row, or call fetchall() to get a list of the matching rows.

Link to [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3)

Below are examples from a table built in the example on documentation

You can `fetchall()` to return all the results

```
cur.execute('select * from lang')
cur.fetchall()
```

You can `fetchone()`to return a single result

```
cur.execute('select * from lang')
cur.fetchone()
```

You can also use the cursor as an iterator

```
for i in cur.execute('select * from lang'):
  i
```